# How to remove first line and last line in a String in android

Tags: java, android, string, pem, pki

**How do i remove first line and last line in this string**

```
String key = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" +
                        "MIGeMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GMADCBiAKBgE0JOa5WUcifbDnnQWB2WKOOODwq\n" +
                        "JUxu/7fG2BaynwVRSifljrzGjqpS24R0ss3cZZSKfD2GszG0aVd5T1Yvh4kSOzsx\n" +
                        "arj8QUkfW/EL5ClhDv8LVtkErbTU42QLUUTl5izyKZXaHFdBnJZ8jqXk4AlK22mp\n" +
                        "LcMadrpv7SzQJq1HAgMBAAE=\n" +
                        "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
```

**I want a output string like this**

```
String key ="MIGeMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GMADCBiAKBgE0JOa5WUcifbDnnQWB2WKOOODwq
    JUxu/7fG2BaynwVRSifljrzGjqpS24R0ss3cZZSKfD2GszG0aVd5T1Yvh4kSOzsx
    arj8QUkfW/EL5ClhDv8LVtkErbTU42QLUUTl5izyKZXaHFdBnJZ8jqXk4AlK22mp
    LcMadrpv7SzQJq1HAgMBAAE="
```

Comment: -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- && -----END PUBLIC KEY----- is this static..?

Comment: split it into an array then remove the first and last element, then convert this array into string

Comment: I hope that you realize that the stuff you want to output isn't valid Java.

Comment: @StephenC Why not? Java does take '/' without problem AFAIK.

Comment: `String[] str = key.split("\n")` then `str[0]=""` and `str[str.length-1]=""` then use a loop to convert this array to `keyString`

Comment: @Vers - Try it and see :-)

Comment: @StephenC I did, that's why I commented :P. It doesn't let you use \ as is though.

Comment: If you did and it worked, then you didn't do it right.  A String literal in Java cannot have line breaks in it.

Comment: Since this is a standard textual public key format, I would probably look for a library that could handle it. Especially if threre’s more you want to do with the public key. Bouncy Castle, for example. It’s not that it’s difficult to do what you’re asking for in pure Java. I’d just want not to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: @StephenC I though you meant the characters, not the line breaks.

Comment: @StephenC i understand you. it's looking like i can't place a dynamic string input like the above format. i am thinking for the solution.

Comment: @DevTamil - You haven't actually explained what you are trying to achieve with all of this.  Are you really transforming one bit of Java source code to another bit of Java source code?  If yes, what is the purpose.  If we don't understand what you are really trying to do here, it is hard to advise you.  And please stop saying "it is a dynamic string".  It is not telling us anything.  (For a start, a string literal in Java source code is NOT a dynamic string.)

Answer (score 5):

If it is stored in a String you can simply call

```
String [] strArr = str.split("\\n");
```

now ignore strArr[0] and strArr[strArr.length-1], and get the rest.

Answer (score 1):

If its static you could do this :

```
key = key.replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
key = key.replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
```

if its not you could use the `split()`method on `\n`maybe and then just keep the center string

Answer (score 0):

as this "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----" and this "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----" are
alwayes have constant length you can use substring.

```
String key = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----" +
            "MIGeMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GMADCBiAKBgE0JOa5WUcifbDnnQWB2WKOOODwq" +
            "JUxu/7fG2BaynwVRSifljrzGjqpS24R0ss3cZZSKfD2GszG0aVd5T1Yvh4kSOzsx" +
            "arj8QUkfW/EL5ClhDv8LVtkErbTU42QLUUTl5izyKZXaHFdBnJZ8jqXk4AlK22mp" +
            "LcMadrpv7SzQJq1HAgMBAAE=" +
            "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
    String result;
    result = key.substring(26,key.length()-24);
```